# Redmine cannot find rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I am trying to migrate a working Redmine instance to another server and am running into problems.

Background: I copied the redmine directory and database to the new server and then attempted to install the corresponding ruby and rails versions necessary. I also installed passenger with `apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger` I bundle installed the gems in the redmine folder.

Now, when I try to load the site, I get

```
cannot load such file -- rails/all (LoadError)
  /srv/redmine/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
  /srv/redmine/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  /srv/redmine/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
  /srv/redmine/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /srv/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
  /srv/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `eval'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

This means my instance cannot find the rails gem, but I have installed it. Not sure what the problem is, nor what diagnostics I have to show as I don't know ruby nor rails well. I may have conflicting versions installed, but I don't really know how to resolve that. I am on Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to `sudo apt-install rails` I am not sure why my system couldn't find rails when I installed the gem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to gem install rails not sudo apt-install rails

1) Go to ur rails app directory 
2) run `bundle install`